# View with multiple textareas, how to identify which was modified?

Tags: elm

I'm making a simple page with multiple `textarea` elements in Elm. I'm struggling to get the data saved and especially identifying which `textarea` was updated. Maybe an example illustrates the point better

I have multiple elements made in view from a list

```
type alias Model = { List Comment, ... }

type alias Comment = {id: Int, content: String, draftContent: String, ...}

type Event = Save Comment | SaveDraft String

-- view
model.comments
|> List.map(     --iterate the list of comments and render html 
div [attrubute "name" "comment"] [
  textarea [onInput SaveDraft] [text comment.content],
  button [onClick (Save comment)] [text "Post comment"]
]

-- update
case event of
  Save comment ->
    -- Replace the comment content with draft data and clear draft

  SaveDraft draftText ->
     -- Update the draft content with text from event
     -- Which Comment is it?
```

Based on examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387409/how-to-submit-a-form-in-elm) I came up with the idea of sending each textarea input as an event to update function and saving the draft data.

Now the problem here is that `onInput` only accepts types with a `String` parameter and I have no means of identifying which one of the comments was modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `Event` union type to include the comment (`SaveDraft String` --> `SaveDraft Comment String`)

```
type Event = Save Comment | SaveDraft Comment String

-- view
model.comments
|> List.map(     --iterate the list of comments and render html 
div [attrubute "name" "comment"] [
  textarea [onInput (SaveDraft comment.content)] [text comment.content],
  button [onClick (Save comment)] [text "Post comment"]
]
```

Currying causes `(SaveDraft comment.content)` to have the same return value as before